# AMD Ryzen 9 5950x Temperature too look out for

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

My specs are:

```
AMD Ryzen 9 5950x
Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080TI
64GB RAM (CORSAIR RGB)
```

With this i have two `Noctua NF-P12` fans and 1x `Noctua NH-D15` fan for the processor

Given these specs i want to look out for my PC and be very careful with it. Because of this i am in doubt if the cooling is enough. Ive attempted to push it with some of the new modern games here it spikes at around 85 degrees.

I dont know much about Processor temperature should i be alarmed?

**Update**

I just tested it using AIDA

With everything on full Load (100%)

The temperature was around 75-76 on the CPU.

So it would seem that some games even if they only take 40% load are heavier? or how should I interpret this result?

Comment: You should only be alarmed if your machine shuts down unexpectedly and you have noticeable thermal throttling.  85C is well within the thermal limits of that processor

Comment: The 85C spike is on 40-50% load shouldnt it be cooler on that type of load?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be alarmed if the computer won't shut down unexpectedly.

The spike on a lower load can be caused by your BIOS settings. They'll set the RPM of your cooling based on the temperature your CPU has.

With some "silent" or "office" modes in the bios or applications by the mainboard manufacturer you'll get higher temperatures with much less load in order to reduce the volume level of your cooling system.

You may want to look for this kind of settings if you don't want this kind of behaviour.

A temperature under full load with about 75°C is pretty good which shows that your cooling solution can handle the heat very well.